# can anyone tell me what does the Soap bindings mean??

Tags: eclipse, web-services, soap, binding, apache-axis

when i create a web service using eclipse 3 types of bindings appear : SOAP12BINDING,HTTPBINDING and SOAP11BINDING what do they refer to ??? am a newbie in Web services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They refer to three different ways of connecting to your web service, SOAP 1.1, SOAP 1.2 and XML over HTTP.

Clients will be able to connect to your service using any of these three protocols, and the server component will form responses with the appropriate protocol.

As far as your server component coding goes, it probably won't make a difference to you which protocol clients choose to use.